# Disk is full when profiling remote process with dotTrace timeline mode

Tags: trace, jetbrains-ide, etw, dottrace

I have a strange error message that systemically occurs when starting profiling a remote process

via dotTrace and it's happening only with timeline mode.

> Unable to continue profiling: Disk is full Start command confirmation
> expected: unknown error (hresult_error:ADAB0005) [location] =
> C:\BuildAgent\work\d843735b9e94e41c\Profiler\Kernel\Windows\Native\Solution\core\src\bridges\etw\etw_bridge.cpp(281)
> [function] = void __thiscall jbprof::etw_bridge::start(struct
> jbprof::snapshot_iface *)

Comment: There is JetBrains support center, sure it's a better way to solve such problems. https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: There is the "Disk is full" error message. Did you check your disk?

Comment: Yes, disk was not full at that moment.

Comment: I see. Well, then @Ed.ward is right, you need to contact JetBrains support center and attach to the ticket all log files from %localappdata%/Temp/Jetlogs and %systemroot%/Temp/Jetlogs folders on the remote machine.